# When running a test with GoogleTest, an SEH exception occurs with a simple variable definition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, mfc

When I ran a unit test using the following procedure, an exception occurred with a simple declaration such as "CString a;".
The environment is Visual Studio 2019 and the language is C++.

- Boot VisualStudio2019
- Click "Create a new project"
- Select "MFC App", Click "Next"
- Set an arbitrary folder for the "Location" item, and click "Create" with the other defaults.
- Leave everything as default and click "Finish".
- A project with the default name "MFCApplication1" will be created.
- Right-click the "MFCApplication1" project in "Solution Explorer" and click "Properties".In "Configuration Properties">"General">"General Properties", set "ISO C++17 Standard(/std:c++17)" in "C++ Language Standard" item.
- Right-click the "MFCApplication1" project in "Solution Explorer" and click "Properties".In "Configuration Properties">"Advanced">"Advanced Properties", set "Use MFC in a Shared DLL" in "Use of MFC" item and set "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" in "Character Set" item. increase.
- Add "SampleClass.cpp" and "SampleClass.h" to your project.

SampleClass.h

```
#pragma once


class _DllExport SampleClass
{
public:
    SampleClass(void);
    virtual ~SampleClass(void);
    char*   sampleMethod();
protected:
private:
};
```

SampleClass.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <string.h>

#include "SampleClass.h"


SampleClass::SampleClass(void) {
}

SampleClass::~SampleClass(void) {
}

char*   SampleClass::sampleMethod() {
    CString a;
    return "test";
}
```

- Add code to pch.h

```
#define _DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )
```

- Build the project and make sure it completes without errors.
- Right-click on the solution in "Solution Explorer" and click Add>New Project...
- Select "Google Test" and click "Next".
- Leave all defaults in "Configure your new project" and click "Create".
- Select "MFCApplication1" at "Select project to test" in "Test Project Configuration" and click "OK" with other items as default.
- A new test project is added with the name "Sample-Test1".
- Right-click the "Sample-Test1" project in "Solution Explorer" and click "Properties".In "Configuration Properties">"General">"General Properties", set "ISO C++17 Standard(/std:c++17)" in "C++ Language Standard" item.
- Right-click the "Sample-Test1" project in "Solution Explorer" and click "Properties".In "Configuration Properties">"Advanced">"Advanced Properties", set "Use MFC in a Shared DLL" in "Use of MFC" item and set "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" in "Character Set" item. increase.
- Right-click the "Sample-Test1" project in "Solution Explorer" and click "Properties". Add "$(ProjectDir)..\MFCApplication1\Debug\MFCApplication1.lib" to "Additional Dependencies" item of "Configuration Properties">"Linker">"Input".
- Add the following code to the "Sample-Test1" project.

test.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "..\MFCApplication1\SampleClass.h"

TEST(TestCaseName, TestSampleMethod) {
    SampleClass sampleClass;
    char* value = sampleClass.sampleMethod();
    EXPECT_TRUE(strcmp(value, "test") == 0);
}
```

- Add code to pch.h of "Sample-Test1" project

```
#define _DllExport   __declspec( dllimport )
```

- Run the build and make sure it completes without errors.
- Right-click the "TestName" item displayed in "Test Explorer" and click "Debug" to debug the test method.
- Then you get an SEH exception at a nondescript code like "CString a;".
  In addition, exceptions will occur at runtime when defining variables such as "std::vector<int>" and processing such as "memset" and "printf".

```
Exception thrown at 0x80000142 in Sample-Test1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x80000142.

unknown file: error: SEH exception with code 0xc0000005 thrown in the test body.
```

A simple test does not pass in a project created with almost default settings. Do I need to configure anything else?
Ultimately, I want to complete the test without any problems with the following code.
All of these raise exceptions when running unit tests.

- Adding variables like "CString" or "std::vector<xxx>" to member variables
- Using local variables for variables like "CString" or "std::vector<xxx>"
- Using standard library functions such as "memset" and "vsprintf_s"
- I tried with the following versions. VS2019 Professional(v16.11, v16.7) and VS2022.
  However, none of the versions fixed the problem.
  I hope it will work in the VS2019 Professional environment.
- I tried not only Google Test but also a native unit test project, but it did not resolve.

Comment: How do you compile `char*   SampleClass::sampleMethod() {
    CString a;
    return "test";
}`? It should not be compiled in C++.

Comment: @273K MSVC by-default allows it and is non-conforming. It will fail it only with `/permissive-` or in C++20 or later mode.

Comment: `#define`ing an identifier starting with underscore followed by uppercase letter causes undefined behavior. These are reserved to the implementation.

Comment: Because I need to unit test a C++ project with "CString".
What I wrote in the question is a simple reproduction procedure.
When I run the test target project itself, it works fine, but I'm in trouble because an exception occurs only during unit tests.

Comment: @user17732522
 I tried changing "_DllExport" defined by #define to "MyDllExport", but the problem was not resolved.

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local string "test" in  sampleMethod, this is incorrect.
Try replacing with `CString sampleMethod() { return CString{"test"}; }`. Returning objects like this is allowed (return value optimization).

Comment: The method described in the explanation column is just a sample, and I don't think it matters what the method should return.
For example, even if you change the contents of the method as follows, the result will not change and an exception will occur at the declaration of "CString".

 `int SampleClass::sampleMethod2() {
    int a; // OK
    CString b; // exception!
    return 1;
}`

I would like to solve the problem that unit tests crash when using "CString" or "std::vector<xxx>" for any processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc:
[Link to object or library files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2022#link-to-object-or-library-files)

> add the output .obj or .lib files to the dependencies of the test
> project.

When you are using not library project you should link to obj file.
And remove `_DllExport`.
For MFC project, you should link->input: SampleClass.obj and PCH.obj in   your GTest Project.
The obj files are in folder: `MFCApplication1\x64\Debug`

Comment: I tried removing "_DllExport" and linking the .obj, but the test method disappeared from Test Explorer.

The other day, I saw a post saying "If the project to be tested is a DLL, it can be tested", and I tried some experiments.
If the project to be tested is a DLL or LIB, it is now possible to test it as a sample project.
However, when I changed the output setting of the MFC application project (not the sample project) that I really wanted to test to DLL or LIB, the build passed but the test methods were not displayed in Test Explorer.

Comment: I cannot reproduce  your problem: test [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNAQP.png).You need to click the green  run button in the test explorer to display the test results.

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of no test method after clicking the run button? Also, please check if the test method is folded. I encountered it the first time I ran the test.  [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32O4L.png)

Comment: What should I do to upload an image to stackoverflow? Maybe stackoverflow doesn't have an image upload function, and is it necessary to use imgur, an external service? (Do I need to create a new imgur account?)

Comment: I uploaded an image.
As you can see, the test method is not displayed even if you click the green button of "Run All Tests".
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cimHm.png

Comment: How about pressing F5 to run the GTest project? https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeBKM.png The current problem is how to test the class of non-library projects. For the second problem of not being able to display 
 Test Method, you should report to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp/report). Thanks  for your understanding. I am using version: Visual Studio Preview.

Comment: >Minxin Yu - MSFT
wonderful!
When I hit F5, it ran the test on the command line and passed the part where the problem was happening without issue.
It may be a VisualStudio bug that test methods are not displayed in Test Explorer.
By pressing F5, the test can be executed without problems, so it seems that the original purpose can be achieved with this.
Thank you very much for all the trial and error.

>273K >user17732522 >Pepijn Kramer
  Thank you for your comment.

Thanks to all of you, I'm glad I was able to resolve it.

Comment: Hi,@camphor tree , If the reply is helpful, you could click '✔' to mark it as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out.
I have put a checkmark in your answer.